# Me ajudem a montar um array com resultado de um foreach com php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Criei uma listagem de alunos que fazem aniversário no mês atual, segue a codificação: **Na codificação abaixo o código está buscando diretamente do banco de dados da tabela student os alunos de todas as turmas que fazem aniversário no mês atual. Class_id mostra na tabela a classe do aluno e Section_id mostra a turma do aluno conforme o foreach.**

```
<?php
 $where = "MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY `student`.`birthday` ASC";
 $this->db->where($where);
 $students = $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
 foreach ($students as $row):

 $class_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => 
 $row['student_id']))->row()->class_id;
 $section_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => 
 $row['student_id']))->row()->section_id;
?>
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei esse código para a view do admin, agora preciso modificar para a view do professor. (Então se faz necessário mostrar apenas os alunos da classe do professor  que está logado.

A tabela que identificar qual a classe e turma do professor é a 'section': Dentro dela consta a class_id, section_id e teacher_id que faz a devida relação.

Esse código o sistema mostra qual o professor está logado:

```
$teachers = $this->db->get_where('teacher', array('teacher_id' => $this->session->userdata('teacher_id')))->result_array();
foreach ($teachers as $teacher):
```

Já esse código mostra a classe pertencente ao professor que está logado:

```
<?php
 $sections = $this->db->get_where('section', array('teacher_id' => $this->session->userdata('teacher_id')))->result_array();
foreach ($sections as $section):

 $class = $this->db->get_where('class', array('class_id' => $section['class_id']))->row();
?>
```

Com esse comando abaixo, é mostrado nome do professor e classe correspondente:

```
<?php echo $teacher['name']; ?> <?php echo $section['name'];?>
```

Minha dificuldade está aqui!!

Preciso que o código busque somente os alunos da classe do professor que está logado. O campo ano escolar da tabela acima (imagem) irá sair. Ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então preciso que o foreach busque apenas os alunos da classe do professor logado (código acima) e não de todas as classes.

**ATUALIZANDO RESULTADO OBTIDO PARA POSSÍVEL SOLUÇÃO**

Acrescentei a variável $student_id aqui:

```
<?php
  $where = "MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY `student`.`birthday` ASC";
  $this->db->where($where);
  $students = $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
  foreach ($students as $row):

 $student_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->student_id;
 $class_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->class_id;
 $section_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->section_id;
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como veem agora só mostra o nome do aluno da classe,**Então pensei seu eu fizer uma condição parecida com a condição abaixo que mostra o nome do aluno da classe dentro do foreach (ele consiga buscar apenas os alunos da classe em questão, o problema é que as variáveis utilizam o $Row, então como criar a condição?**

Condição para mostrar apenas o nome do aluno aniversariante da classe;

```
<?php if ($student_id ==  $row['student_id'] && $section_id ==  $section['section_id'])
echo $row['name']; ?>
```

**Consegui resolver, obrigado a todos:** O que fiz?!

```
<?php
 $where = "MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY `student`.`birthday` ASC";
 $this->db->where($where);
 $students = $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
 foreach ($students as $row){

  $student_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->student_id;
  $class_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->class_id;
  $section_id = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->section_id;

  if ($student_id ==  $row['student_id'] && $section_id ==  $section['section_id']) break;
 }
?>
```

Comment: A sessão armazena oque?

Comment: @Lucas Antonio -> Armazena o id do professor.

Comment: E o professor está logado certo?

Comment: Isso. @Lucas Antonio.

Comment: @Lucas Antonio, Acredito que eu deva filtrar a variável $students pegado dela o student_id e comparando com o student_id da tabela enroll (que faz o armazenamento todos os alunos atribuindo a classe (class_id) e turma (section_id) antes do foreach.

Comment: Tipo assim: $aniversariantes = this .. student_id onde student_id é igual student_id da tabela enroll que também é igual a class_id e section_id do professor logado.

Comment: Seu problema é simples amigo

Comment: Recupera o id da session e faz um where a onde lista os alunos, claro os alunos com relacionamento com o professor e no where você pega id do professor igual o da sessão e então retorna alunos do professor.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97036/discussion-between-pedro-paulo-and-lucas-antonio).